# Fluid and static divs on same row

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I have a question regarding fluid layouts. I'm building a responsive site, and I have a Listview I've built with DIVs. What I'm trying to do is this:

I have a list of items, each with several different data entries (title, year, genre, options), each in their own DIV (all of them are inside a wrapping DIV). 2 of those have a fixed width, like the date (YYYY-MM-DD). It's always the same width, as is the options (2 icons).

How do I build this so that the title and genre div have fluid widths and change, and the date and option div stays the same width.

I've tried setting widths in percent, but that means it recalculates as I resize the window. I want date for example to have the same width on all break points. No matter if you view it on the iPhone or desktop.

Appreciate any and all ideas!

Comment: Please post some code, and eventually add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to show what you tried!

Answer (score 0):

Give everyone the fluid width ie- `width:90%`, only you have to do is to define `min-width:240px;` only for the elements you want to fix those widths results they'll no more be stretched further the limit.